# Copy/paste objects make them offset from path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I've been having this problem lately where whenever I copy/paste something from a different Ai doc into another Ai doc the path is offset from the object. This has only started happening recently and It's starting to become slightly annoying. I've tried restarting the program and such. I'm using CC 2015.

Here's a picture:
[image]

Comment: Straight paste always pastes in the *center* of the active artboard.

Comment: @Scott Yes I know, I'm not having issues with pasting to the artboard, its that the path of the pasted object isn't on the object itself.

Comment: So wait, you're saying that blue box is not a transparent (or white) object but rather the path for the purple object??

Comment: @Ryan yep thats exactly what I'm saying. Sorry, I should've clarified better.

Comment: Working real small and align to pixel grid on???  Otherwise who knows.. could be an effect as @Ryan points out in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you up to date? 19.1 allegedly fixed the issue

Comment: d'oh! That was it! Can't believe I forgot to update. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Appearance Style** is probably the cause. Only thing we ([in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot)) have come up with anyways. If you have an Appearance Style using a `Free Distort` then you could end up with the result you're seeing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So from what I've noticed it sometimes is related to the Appearance panel if the object does have styles, but other times like with the purple square which has no appearance style besides being purple with no stroke it resolves it on its own somehow. Maybe it's just a weird glitch type deal? Thanks for your help nonetheless though!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your document settings. The new doc may be set to "align new objects to pixel grid". Or, in your transform palette options the new document may be set to "align pixels to grid".

Comment: That option isn't checked in either doc. I'm starting to think its something in CC 2015 since this never happened in the 2014 version.